# How can I follow a webapp log in NetBeans for the included Tomcat server?

Tags: logging, netbeans

I'm running a webapp using the included tomcat server in NetBeans. NetBeans shows me the Tomcat log in the output window, but I also want to see my webapp's log. Is this possible? Can I configure NetBeans to do this? I can't find any options in the server or project settings so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the log configuration of your web-app, did you made the webapp yourself, is it one of the netbeans webprojects, maven archetype, etc. ?

Comment: It's uPortal, an open source web portal. I can make changes to the webapp, but I wouldn't know what I need to do. If you can tell me how to get a log into the output window, I can figure out how to do it for my particular application.

Comment: that's not the way it works normally, the web-app logs (or not) and if it logs the output goes into the tomcat log (normally), you need to look into the documentation of uPortal for some infos about the logging, if there are no informations, mail a developer

Comment: So it's assumed that all log output goes into the Tomcat log? Interesting... That would probably indicate that NetBeans isn't going to be interested in catching other logs...

Comment: I think this answer doesn't solve the problem. Only adds conditions to the question. Should be good to show an example of a basic application

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.